# ¿Cómo subir mi proyecto dividido en frontend y backend a heroku?

Tags: angular, heroku

Mi proyecto esta organizado asi: una **carpeta bookstore** y adentro dos carpetas mas:
una **frontend** y la otra **server**.
en **frontend** esta todo lo referido a **Angular** con su carpeta **node_modules**
y su archivo **package.json** etc.. y en **server** esta todo lo referido a **node/express** tambien con su propia carpeta **node_modules** y **su package.json**.
Viendo tutoriales de como hacer **deploy a heroku**, veo que no tienen el proyecto
dividido en dos partes como es en mi caso (frontend y server), por lo que todas
las configuraciones las hacen en un **solo package.json**.
Hay una forma de resolver este problema?, ¿una alternativa seria crear en heroku
dos app, una app para la carpeta frontend y la otra para server?.

aca muestro en imagenes como esta organizado el proyecto:

**carpeta frontend**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**carpeta server**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por que no intentas meter Angular dentro del lado del server? Puedes usar Angular Universal https://angular.io/guide/universal.

Comment: Gracias, no conocia Angular universal!, de todos modos lo que hice fue crear dos app en heroku, una para el frontend y la otra para el backend.

Comment: A mi me gusta trabajar siempre con la api separada de angular. Es más fácil el mantenimiento una vez desplegada. Se utilizan dos package.json, y para desplegar la aplicación de angular lo que se crea es un servidor express que sirva los archivos compilados después de que heroku ejecuta el script heroku-postbuild.